# What is the the full name of TAPD? Structure provided

Tags: nomenclature

I have a substituent called TAPD on a molecule I'm working with. I have a hard time locating information about its properties. The bold square in the picture below is supposed to be the rest of the system on which the TAPD is attached. I am a physicist and thus not very good at chemical naming, so I would have good use of some help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TAPD = Tetraalkyl-​p-​phenylenediamine**

This is because you have a phenyl (benzenoid) ring, with two amino groups (diamine) opposite (**p**ara) to each other, and each of those amino groups has two alkyl substituents, giving four (tetra) in total.